# Is it safe to use a pointer to a variable after the end of the function?

Tags: c++, c++20

If I have a global pointer, and I initialize it like this:

```
Image *fbPtr = NULL;
...
void initFrameBuffer(const BootInfo::FrameBuffer &info) {
    Image fb(info.getWidth(), info.getHeight(), info.getBpp(), info.getBuf());
    fbPtr = &fb;
}
```

Would it be undefined behaviour? Would the fb variable be deleted by the end of the function and the pointer be rendered invalid?
I'm using GCC10 and compiling with -std=c++2a, if it makes any difference.

Comment: Yes, it's UB to access the value at `fbPtr` outside the function. That hasn't changed in c++20.

Comment: What would make you think it would be valid? The only way it's valid is if `fb` outlives the function; make it `static`, and it's legal, otherwise, nope.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is undefined behavior, specifically the use of a pointer to a variable on the stack (variables defined without the new keyword) is called a dangling pointer. In this case you can simply replace the function body with this:

```
void initFrameBuffer(const BootInfo::FrameBuffer &info) {
    Image * fb = new Image(info.getWidth(), info.getHeight(), info.getBpp(), info.getBuf());
    fbPtr = fb;
}
```

This defines image as a pointer and allocates the data on the heap instead of the stack. This also means that you need to eventually delete it with `delete fbPtr;`, or else the image object will remain taking up memory forever. If you change the fbPtr variable without deleting the contents, this will cause a memory leek, meaning your program is repeatedly allocating more memory without ever deallocating it, meaning eventually you will run out of memory.

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes I've fixed it now